# MBED BLE Payload values

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, mbed

I am working on a BLE Scanner.Basically I am looking for an iBeacon device with 0x4c type and a payload size of 30. However when i run this mbed crashes after spitting out few print lines. This code is very hit and miss.
it is getting an index out of bound error(understandably). How do I catch the error and skip it?

```
    void Scanner::onAdvertisingReport(const AdvertisingReportEvent &event)
{  
    printf("Looking for Devices\r\n");
    AdvertisingDataParser adv_data(event.getPayload());
    while(adv_data.hasNext())
    {     
        if (event.getPayload().size() == 30 and event.getPayload()[5] == 0x4c)
        {
            beacon_found = true;

            while(beacon_found)
            {
                printf("Found Beacon!\r\n");
                ::print_address(event.getPeerAddress());
                printf("RSSI : %d\r\n",event.getRssi());
                printf("PL: %d\r\n",event.getPayload().size());
             
                printf("Major Value: %d\r\n",event.getPayload()[26]);
                printf("Minor Value: %d\r\n",event.getPayload()[27]);
                break;
            }   
            beacon_found = false;
            break;

                
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Couldnt find beacon!\r\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    adv_data.next();
}
```

Error:
Error Status: 0x80FF0140 code 324 module 255
Assertion failed: 0 <= index && index < _size in Span.h

Comment: Show the code you have written so far.

Comment: Hi I am sorry I have updated the question a bit. It would be very helpful if you could help me solve it

Comment: for one thing `adv_data.next();` doesn't seem to be controlled by `while(adv_data.hasNext())` and your inner while loop seems nonsensical and its break misplaced.

Comment: As far as I can see, `AdvertisingDataParser` isn't really used. It would return `element_t` instances but they are never used.

Comment: The conclusion is: remove the `AdvertisingDataParser` instance, remove the outer *while* loop, remove the *break* statements, remove `adv_data.next()`.